# Retrieving duplicate records from a BigQuery table when only table name is known

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a process that would include a step to check for duplicates in a BigQuery table. At the point of checking, I only know the table name. I don't know the number of columns and their names.

To retrieve the column names I reckoned I could leverage `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table and use it in my SQL but I'm not getting my desired result.

This is my code:

```
select
  * except(row_number)
from (
  select
    *, row_number() over (partition by (SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name) column_names FROM `proj.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` WHERE table_name = 'users')) as row_number
    --*, row_number() over (partition by (SELECT split(STRING_AGG(column_name),',') column_names FROM `proj.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` WHERE table_name = 'users')) as row_number
  from  `proj.dataset.users`)
where row_number > 1
```

Test data

```
name,age,country
Patrick,22,UK
James,12,UK
James,12,UK
Josh,33,Canada
Josh,33,Canada
```

My result

```
name,age,country
James,12,UK
James,12,UK
Josh,33,Canada
Josh,33,Canada
```

Desired result

```
name,age,country
James,12,UK
Josh,33,Canada
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `to_json_string()` with a struct.  And qualify to simplify the query a bit:

```
select u.*
from `proj.dataset.users` u
where true
qualify row_number() over (partition by to_json_string(u)) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. I did make some changes to your code for it to work. Qualify has to be used with a `where` clause, so I added a `where true`. Also I added the `()` for the row_number function. Perhaps you may want to update your code.

Comment: also I think it should be `= 1` instead of `> 1` :o)

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select any_value(t).*
from `proj.dataset.users` t 
group by format('%t', t)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Could you a line explaining how that works